# Rails 3 - SQL query in a more "rails way"

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I want to know if you know how to write the following sql query in a
more "rails way"

```
UPDATE  buy_order_detail
SET saldo = saldo - detail_purchase.cantidad
FROM purchase_detail
           INNER JOIN purchase ON purchase.id =
purchase_detail.purchase_id
           INNER JOIN waybill ON waybill.id =
purchase.waybill_id
           INNER JOIN buy_order ON buy_order.id =
waybill.order_id
           INNER JOIN buy_order_detail ON buy_order.id =
buy_order_detail.order_id
WHERE purchase_detail.product_id = buy_order_detail.product_id
```

---

I've tried something like this, in the "DetailPurchase model"

```
def after_create
    pchs = Purchase.find(self.purchase_id)
    wbl = Waybill.find(pchs.waybill_id)
    bdr = BuyOrder.find(wbl.buy_order_id)
   BuyOrderDetail.find_by_buy_order_id(bdr.id).where(:product_id => self.product_id).update_attribute(:saldo, buy_order_detail.saldo - cantidad)
  end
```

But when I check the value "saldo", it always keep the same original value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing the question using the Rails Way, would implore that you

1. write [Models](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-model)
2. use [Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#associating-models) between the models to define their relations
3. call upon [Model.find()](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#showing-an-individual-post) with some conditions to generate the SQL (automatically and out-of-sight)

All these steps (and more) are explained in the [Getting Started with Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

With Ruby on Rails one (normally) does not generate SQL directly. But data from a database is modeled by (duh) Models. These models are used by Rails to retrieve the requested information from the database. Basically, you could say that each Model corresponds with a table in the database (at least for simple situations).

Comment: Excuse me, but do you have an example? I've tried to solve this using callbacks with the Model.update_attribute(), I've tried with Model.where(), and I've tried with Model.find()... Unfortunately Nothing seems to work

Comment: @Angelo, Not that you know the Rail Way, I think it is best to post a new question. Show in that question what what you already have and tell what part is not working correctly.

Comment: ok, I've posted a [new question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032067/ruby-on-rails-3-join-many-models-to-update-a-field-of-one-model-using-attribute) to try to explain my problem in a better way